# External href buttons don't work in HTML. Internal buttons work perfectly

Tags: javascript, html, button, hyperlink, href

So I created this website for someone and all of my internal links to different page sections are working but the external links don't.

The external links were definetly working in the first place. Not sure what happen during development. My source code is massive so I am not sure where to put it.

I can put a the link buttons although I am sure that is more to do with something else reather than the way I wrote the code for buttons.

HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?saddr=My%20Location&daddr=Papagayo%20cafe,%2097%20High%20Rd,%20London%20NW10%202SL" target="_blank" class="cta-button">
       DIRECTIONS
    </a>
```

I disabled AdBlock and tried to run the website from a different browser but no luck

CSS:

```
 .cta-button:link,
 .cta-button:visited{ 
  border: 0.3rem solid none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 0.5rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  margin-top:3rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  background-color: #671934 ;
   font-weight: 700;
  }

 .cta-button:hover,
 .cta-button:active {
  color: #555;
  background-color: white ;
   }
```

Some JS code related to my links, although it DID WORK PREVIOUSLTY WITH EXTERNAL LINKS AS WELL ON THE SAME CODE. Don't know what happen in the mantime

```
// Scroll-behaviour: smooth -- working in safari as well//

  const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a:link");

    allLinks.forEach(function (link) {
       link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const href = link.getAttribute("href");
        console.log(href);

//Scroll back to the top
if (href === "#")
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 20,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });

// Scroll smoothly to a specific section
if (href !== "#" && href.startsWith("#")) {
  const selectionEl = document.querySelector(href);
  selectionEl.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
}

//Close navitation bar
if (link.classList.contains("main-nav-link"))
  header.classList.toggle("nav-open");

   });
 });
```

The internal links to sections or menu work nicely..

I looked at similar questions on here and tried their suggesions but nothing worked

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` prevents the default action. And in the example provided, none of the if-statements are run, so nothing else happens.

Comment: Any idea of what to use instead of e.preventDefault(); in order to get all the other conditions to run ?

Maybe another if statement , but not sure how to formulate it, thanks !

Comment: Try checking your if-statements against the url hash when the page loads.